# How to preserve state when view controller gets unloaded due to memory warnings?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, automatic-ref-counting

I think this might just come down to me not completely understanding the correct thing to do when an app gets a memory warning (or maybe I don't understand what iOS does on its own when you get a memory warning).

Here is a simplified version of my problem:

I have a `RootViewController`. It pushes a `TextViewController` where I have a `UITextField`. The `TextViewController` can push a `DetailViewController` that shows some details.

If I push all the way to the `DetailsViewController`, so that my navigation view controller stack is `[RootVC, TextVC, DetailVC]`, and then simulate a memory warning, `TextVC` gets unloaded from memory automatically by iOS.

**Problem 1:** iOS just decided my view controller should be unloaded. When the user pops `DetailVC` to get back to `TextVC`, where am I supposed to save the state information (e.g. the text entered in the text field)? Right now, the text field just goes back to blank because the view controller got unloaded and then reloaded.

<strike>**Problem 2:** When I pop back to `TextVC` and tap the text field, my app crashes. Turning on zombies revealed that some `UIView` was getting a `responderDidBecomeActive:` message from somewhere when I tapped on the text field. How is this even possible with ARC? In my `viewDidUnload` method I am setting the text field to nil and even setting its delegate property to nil.</strike>

EDIT. **New question:** I just totally fixed everything by overriding `didReceiveMemoryWarning` for `TextVC` and having it not do anything. On a scale from 1 to really bad, how bad is this?

EDIT 2. **Just kidding,** I'm an idiot and forgot to remove an observer for a notification in a totally different but related piece of code. I still don't understand how/where state information is supposed to be saved when iOS just throws out your crap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way to think of this is as follows. When you get the viewDidUnload, the system has purged all the UI elements. When you pop back to your view, the system will reload the nib, and you will get viewDidLoad (again), and obviously all data and settings will have been lost.

The solution to this is in any viewConroller that might get unloaded, you would save any data the user entered or set in ivars - you would save the text in NSString for intstance. In viewDidLoad, you can look at that string, and if there is data in it initialize the text field.

All of what I told you is relevant to ios5. Apple will be changing what it does regarding this in the future, but I cannot really talk about it here as what I learned at WWDC is under non-disclosure. That said, you can probably find it pretty quickly by looking at some WWDC videos or reading the private developer lists. You should be really happy about what you will learn!

Comment: I haven't looked at the new NDA stuff yet so I'm glad to hear they're addressing some of this. I have a strong NSString property that I am setting to the text field's value, but when I trigger the memory warning and the view gets unloaded and then I try to access the property in `viewDidLoad`, it's back to nil. Am I missing something...?

Comment: Never mind, everything's working as it should. It sounds silly now that I think about it, but it hadn't occurred to me in years of iOS development that the *view* gets unloaded here, not the *view controller*.

Comment: I believe everything in the nib gets unloaded, but now I'm questioning that! For sure view and anything in the view! In a few months its all going to change though - for the better!